# How to improve quality of sent images with Telegram Bot API

Tags: java, telegram-bot

I'm using Telegram Bot API to send images like

```
SendDocument newDocMessage = new SendDocument().setDocument(path.toFile());
```

or

```
SendPhoto newPhotoMessage = new SendPhoto().setPhoto(path.toFile());
SendPhoto newPhotoMessageStream = new SendPhoto().setPhoto("Image", stream);
```

, but the quality of images sent with SendPhoto is much worse than SendDocument (so image on server is ok).
I know Telegram compressing images in any cases, but even when I uploading same image with mobile application or from desktop - the quality is much better.

Is there a way to send image (not as document) using Bot API with same quality as uploaded from desktop/mobile application?

Comment: I have stumbled across the same problem. Were you able to fix it? If so how?

Comment: Unfortunately, as per answer from Telegram Bot Support, no, it's platform limitation.

Comment: Ok. I was able to improve the quality a little, by increasing the resolution of the original image file 2x.